# Verify how an Instant App in Android is launched

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

According to the documentations, an Instant App is downloaded via Google Play and launched on the fly. It is not installed but is rather cached in the Android system. As a developer and user, I would like to validate this behaviour.

I have tried running Clash Royale by hitting the "Try now" - that is when a splash screen is shown with a progress bar (assuming that's when the feature APK is downloaded?) and it launches soon. On exit, there is no application icon which is expected.

In the device storage I looked for trace of the APK but with no success. Do I need ROOT permissions to see this? Is there a way to inspect and verify?

Answer (score 1):

There is **still** an APK installed.

For O+ devices, run `adb shell pm path com.supercell.clashroyale` after `TRY NOW`

And you'll see:

```
package:/data/app/com.supercell.clashroyale-CUaYOumzCbUDNAdv1MRtRg==/base.apk
package:/data/app/com.supercell.clashroyale-CUaYOumzCbUDNAdv1MRtRg==/split_split_2_tutorial_battles.apk
```

Do it again after `INSTALL` (for comparison), and you'll see:

```
package:/data/app/com.supercell.clashroyale-0Dn0s6yq6WqGCRZ9ETT8bA==/base.apk
package:/data/app/com.supercell.clashroyale-0Dn0s6yq6WqGCRZ9ETT8bA==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk
package:/data/app/com.supercell.clashroyale-0Dn0s6yq6WqGCRZ9ETT8bA==/split_config.en.apk
package:/data/app/com.supercell.clashroyale-0Dn0s6yq6WqGCRZ9ETT8bA==/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk
```

*(For pre-O devices, the first part won't work, but I don't know any other cmd that will do the same)*

Comment: The packages only show up for me when I install. When I try checking without installing and using TRY NOW, I do not see any packages listed.

Comment: Android OS of the device you are using? pre-O or O+?

Comment: It's Android 6.0.1 Marshmallow

Comment: Hmm, you're right, I tested this on an N device and didn't see any results after TRY NOW, only until after INSTALL. I had tested that cmd on an O device. I do know that instant apps runs differently underneath between pre-O vs O+ because it wasn't built into the OS in pre-O, but sorry, I don't know of any other cmd to do this in pre-O then.

Comment: Thanks for the information. This is an interesting find.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to Settings -> Apps, and see instant apps there. The App Icon will have Lightning bolt sub-icon at least it looks like that on Samsung Android 12.