# Google Play Instant Apps (AOT or JIT)

Tags: java, android, android-instant-apps

Standing on what wikipedia say in past the Apps uses **JIT** (just in time) compilation where the apps is translated into machine code every time was executed and in new android versions apps uses AOT(ahead of time) compilation where the apps code is translated in machine code during the first installation.

So how work the new Instant APPs feature, it uses the old **JIT** or the new **AOT** because the app is not installed but executed immediately?

Comment: The app is still installed, just like a regular app, so still AOT.

Comment: I am actually not really shure about your answer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60122182/6668797, you can verify that it is installed